# May I know why it shows unable to locate element?

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver  
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome('ChromeDriver')
driver.get("https://devbusiness.tunai.io/login")
time.sleep(2)
driver.maximize_window()

#log in credentials
username = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "loginUsername");
username.send_keys("kevin@tunai");

password = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "loginPassword");
password.send_keys("xxxxx");

login = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='app']/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[4]/button");
login.submit();
time.sleep(3)

driver.get("https://devbusiness.tunai.io/dashboard/salon_report_voucher")
time.sleep(3)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="packageTable"]/tbody[1]/tr/td[1]').click()
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="packageTable"]/tbody[1]/tr').click()
time.sleep(2)

#trigger the element before click
voucher = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='packageTable']/tbody[2]/tr[1]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", voucher)
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="packageTable"]/tbody[2]/tr[1]')
time.sleep(2)

#trigger the detail button
detail = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='checkAll']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", detail)
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='checkAll']")
time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="voucherModal___BV_modal_body_"]/div/div/button[1]').click()
time.sleep(5)
```

I wanna click on the edit new price and enter a new price, save it and loop it. For now, I am not allow to enter the new price and proceed. I copied the Xpath and tried, but it failed so i m thinking because of the popout page. thats why it failed.

Comment: The credentials here are wrong. We can't help without actual debugging

Comment: At which step are you exactly stuck? What error do you see?

Answer (score 1):

To click on `Edit Price` button. use webdriverwait() and wait for element to be clickable and following `xpath`.

Then wait for model to pop up and then enter the value.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='voucherModal___BV_modal_content_']//button[text()='Edit Price']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='voucherEditModal___BV_modal_content_']//input[@data-maska-tokens]"))).click()    
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='voucherEditModal___BV_modal_content_']//input[@data-maska-tokens]"))).send_keys("1000")
```

you need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```